# Logic App For Each Loop to detect empty space

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic app with nested For each loop which has an array looped in as below:-

@items('For_each')?['TicketAssignedTo']  --> This could some times get black array values like "TicketAssignedTo": [ ] which make the loop to succeed but Insert SQL block within this loop would not execute. How to detect these blank values and make the control execute the inner block ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`length function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#length) in the expression. Also be mindful to coalesce the value to an empty string before checking the length.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "If" condition in you logic app to judge the length of your array.
[image]

The expression of length is
[image]

but maybe you should use

```
length(body('xxx'))
```

it depends on the source of your array.